# Coding with FFMPEG in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I succesfully compiled ffmpeg for Android, but I don't know how I can programatically convert flv or mp4 files to mp3, but I need it. Can anybody help me with example or tutorial? Thank you.

Comment: you are familiar with the use of the ndk?

Comment: i familiar with ndk a little bit.

Comment: if i understand this right, you will have to use ffmpeg from a C library, and usually call this via JNI in java. you may try to start with this http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ or consider using the CLI, which is definitely easier (and which you can use from java directly) http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: thank yout for helping. I saw this examples, but I don't understand - how can I use CLI? Or you don't know about ability to use CLI in android?

Comment: on a device with ffmpeg installed, you can call use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html to call a program

Comment: This is code for my task "ffmpeg -i source_video.avi -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192 -f mp3 sound.mp3". Can you check it and give me a sample for CLI call? Please. I compiled ffmpeg and created easy function, but I don't know how use it with CLI call.

Answer (score 1):

A good example on how to use an FFmpeg binary compiled for Android via CLI, using `ProcessBuilder`, is available here:

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/blob/master/src/org/ffmpeg/android/FfmpegController.java

Note the method:

```
private int execProcess(String cmd, ShellCallback sc, File fileExec) throws IOException, InterruptedException { 

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    pb.directory(fileExec);

    Log.d(TAG,cmd);

    // pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = pb.start();


    // any error message?
    StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new
    StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR", sc);

    // any output?
    StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new
    StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", sc);

    // kick them off
    errorGobbler.start();
    outputGobbler.start();

    int exitVal = process.waitFor();

    sc.processComplete(exitVal);

    return exitVal;
}
```